# Angular Ag-grid(Value Getter not exporting rendered value for the cell)

Tags: angular, typescript, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular, exceljs

I am using angular ag-grid and I have a column definition as following.

```
columnDefs=[

{field:'rate' , sortable:true, filter:true, headerName: " RATE", valueGetter: this.rateValueGetter }
```

rateValueGetter function is as following.

```
rateValueGetter(params): String {

if(params.colDef.field=="rate"){

if(params.data.rate.includes('1')) return 'Y';

}

if(params.colDef.field=="rate"){

if(params.data.rate.includes('0')) return 'N';

}

}
```

Essentially what the above function does is that if the rate field in the database is 1, it will render Y on the frontend , otherwise if its 0, it will render N.

The problem occurs when I try to export the grid data using a third party library exceljs, it doesn't export the rendered value(Y or N ), instead it exports the original data(1 or 0)...how do i get it to export rendered value? From what i understand, valuegetter doesn't actually change the data, it just renders the value on the screen so when i am trying to export the data, its not getting the rendered value. Is there anyway to get rendered value? thank you. Below is my export function.

```
    btnExport(){
    
    let filtereddata=[];
    
    this.gridApi.forEachNodeAfterFilterAndSort(grd=> {
    
    filtereddata.push(grd.data);
    
    });
this.exportService.exportDataAsExcel(filtereddata, this.columnDefs, "filename");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `map` for `filtereddata` to transform data before export.

Example:

```js
filtereddata.map(data => {
 return {
   ...data,
   rate: data.rate.includes('1') ? 'Y' : 'N'
 }
})
```